# Rails undefined method 'generated_methods' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Okay so I was just starting this rails app and generated my first model

> ruby script/generate model Grid req:string class:string ctitle:string credits:float grade:string pass:boolean

created my table

> rake db:migrate
>   (in C:/Users/Michael/InstantRails/rails_apps/studentGrid)
>   ==  CreateGrids: migrating ====================================================
>   -- create_table(:grids)
>      -> 0.0150s
>   ==  CreateGrids: migrated (0.0150s) ===========================================

and went to the console to add some data to my table

> > Grid
> >     => Grid(id: integer, req: string, class: string, ctitle: string, credits: float,
> >      grade: string, pass: boolean, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
> >     Grid.create(:req=>"Math Elective", :class=>"Math 111", :ctitle=>"Calculus I", :credits=>3.0)

Pretty standard I thought, but then I get this error and I don't understand why

NoMethodError: undefined method `'generated_methods' for nil:NilClass
        from C:/Users/Michael/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesup
port-2.3.5/lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:52:in`method_missing'
        from C:/Users/Michael/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerec
ord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:352:in `respond_to?'
        from C:/Users/Michael/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerec
ord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/base.rb:2746:in`attributes='
        from C:/Users/Michael/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerec
ord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/base.rb:2742:in `each'
        from C:/Users/Michael/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerec
ord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/base.rb:2742:in`attributes='
        from C:/Users/Michael/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerec
ord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/base.rb:2438:in `initialize'
        from C:/Users/Michael/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerec
ord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/base.rb:721:in`new'
        from C:/Users/Michael/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerec
ord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/base.rb:721:in `create'
        from (irb):2
        from :0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd try renaming the `class` column to something else. See [here](http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/reservedwords) for other terms to avoid.